# Is there a way of skipping to the end of the output in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a command that displays very long output—for example, the "help" command.

I want it to skip to the end right away (to the part where it says "PS C:\Users\User"), but I also want it to print all of the lines (so I don't want to use Ctrl+C).

Currently, I have to hold down Enter (there's "-- More -- " on the last row) and then it slowly prints the lines, but I had to give up before reaching the end.

Is this even possible? I didn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `help` *function* wraps the [`Get-Help`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help?) *cmdlet*<sup>[1]</sup> expressly to provide *interactive output paging* for lengthy help texts, on Windows by default via the - bare-bones - `more.com` utility.<sup>[2]</sup>

Simply call `Get-Help` rather than `help` to bypass the interactive paging.

---

<sup>[1] You can see the definition (body) of this function if you execute
`$function:help`. Note that if neither a *function* nor an *alias* named `help` existed, `help` would implicitly call `Get-Help`, because the verb `Get` is the *default* verb; however, as this example shows, relying on the default verb is best avoided, both for the potential to be preempted by commands with that specific name (see [about_Command_Precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Precedence)) and because it makes the invocation slow.</sup>

<sup>[2] `more.com` only allows *forward* paging and doesn't support skipping directly to the beginning or end of the output (run `more.com /?` for details). However, you can override what pager program PowerShell uses, allowing you to substitute a more sophisticated pager, such as `less` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59240939/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.  It would only show the last 24 lines.

```
help get-childitem | select -Last 24
```